# Azure Pipelines: Create universal build for OSX with both arm and intel support

Tags: azure, macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, apple-m1

I am trying to build a universal application that runs both on arm and intel on Mac.
Now while I can set the `-arch` flag manually I do not find that possibility on Azure Pipelines.
I tried this by adding `arch: "arm64"` but a `x86_64` build was triggered.

```
    - task: Xcode@5
      displayName: 'Build App'
      inputs:
        actions: 'archive'
        scheme: 'app'
        sdk: '$(sdk)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        xcWorkspacePath: '$(xcodeproj)'
        xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath
        signingOption: 'manual'
        signingIdentity: '$(CERT)'
        teamId: $(TeamID)
        args: 'DSTROOT="$(BuildRoot)"'
        arch: "arm64"
```

How can I build for M1?

Comment: Thx but all of this is either outdated or has nothing to do with azure pipelines. My Question would be how cross-compiling is possible.

Comment: Can't you just add it in the 'args' parameters of the Xcode@5 task?

Comment: The [Xcode task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops) does not have an "arch" input.

Comment: @Bruno you should post that as an Answer.

Comment: Waiting for the OP, to confirm if that's what he wants :)

Comment: @Bruno Yes this is what I want and it works. You could post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by OP.

You need to pass the additional arguments to the task in the 'args' parameter:

```
  - task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Build App'
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive'
    scheme: 'app'
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(xcodeproj)'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(CERT)'
    teamId: $(TeamID)
    args: '-arch arm64 DSTROOT="$(BuildRoot)"'
```

**UPDATE**:
If you want a universal build this would be the case:

```
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Build App'
  inputs:
    actions: 'archive'
    scheme: 'App'
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(xcodeproj)'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(CERT)'
    teamId: $(TeamID)
    args: 'DSTROOT="$(BuildRoot)" ARCHS="x86_64 arm64"'
```